# Aggregate dated events in Analysis Services OLAP Cube

Tags: ssas, aggregation, cube

I have a table with columns that store dates of various events, like so:

```
<pre>
PersonID  DatePassedExam1 DatePassedExam2
   1      NULL            NULL
   2      01-11-2012      NULL
   3      01-12-2012      10-12-2012
</pre>
```

I want to build a cube to see counts of people who have passed exam1 and exam2 by person attributes and time, e.g. year to date.

So,

```
YTD for Oct2012: exam1count=0, exam2count=0  
YTD for Nov2012: exam1count=1, exam2count=0  
YTD for Dec2012: exam1count=2, exam2count=1
```

I'm guessing this needs semi-additive aggregation?

I can't make changes in the database (without difficulty) and am not using Enterprise edition.

Any advice gratefully received.

Thanks,
Dal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would unpivot your table to pass the columns: PersonID , Exam , DatePassed.  Your sample data would result in 1 row for PersonID 2 and 2 rows for PersonID 3.

I would then create an Exam dimension and link it.

Then I would create the measure as a Distinct Count of PersonID.

Comment: You are welcome.  Mark it as the Answer to assist future generations.